# Why does Mathematica compute zero centrality scores for these weighted adjacency matrices?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The adjacency matrix with weights on each edges are as shown below.

```
adjCitationData = {
    {18, 5, 2,  4 ,   9,  0,  0,  5, 0, 3,   1,   5,    0,   0},
    {  3, 6, 0,  2 ,   2,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0,   0,   1,   0,    0},
    {  1, 3, 3,  4 ,   3,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0,   0,   1,   0,    0},
    {  9, 0, 0, 68,  25,  0,  0,  0, 0, 6,  12,   0,   6,    0},
    {19, 4, 1, 57, 139,  0,  0, 0, 0, 7,  62,  0,  44,  0},
    {  1, 0, 0,  0 ,   0,  5,  4,  0, 0,  0,   0,    0,   0,   0},
    {  1, 0, 0,  0 ,   0,  3,  2,  0, 0,  0,   0,    0,   0,   0},
    {  6, 0, 0,  0 ,   1,  0,  0,  2, 0,  0,   0,    3,   0,   0},
    {  0, 0, 0,  0 ,   0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0,   0,    0,   0,   0},
    {  0, 0, 0,  0 ,   0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0,   0,    0,   0,   0},
    {  8, 2, 0, 44 , 85, 0,  0,  0, 0,  4,  53,   0,  35,  0},
    {  8, 1, 0,  0 ,   1,  1,  0,  2, 0,  0,   0,    6,   0,   0},
    {  1, 0, 0, 25 , 59,  0,  0, 0, 0,  1,  47,   0,  37,  0},
    {  0, 0, 0,  0 ,   0,   0,  0,  0, 0,  0,    0,    0,   0,   0} }

adjPSODynamicsData = {
   {0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {4, 4, 10, 2, 2, 4, 10, 3, 8, 2, 2, 5, 7, 9},
   {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {3, 5, 0, 4, 1, 6, 0, 5, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3},
   {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2},
   {0, 0, 0, 3 , 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 1, 0, 0 , 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
   {0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
   };

WeightedAdjacencyGraph@adjPSODynamicsData

pts[m_, r_] := Module[{pts, CCr, CCm, BCr, BCm, EVCr, EVCm},
  pts = 0;
  
  BCm = Mean[BetweennessCentrality@WeightedAdjacencyGraph@m];
  BCr = Mean[BetweennessCentrality@WeightedAdjacencyGraph@r];
  
  (*EVCr=Mean[EigenvectorCentrality@WeightedAdjacencyGraph@m];
  EVCm=Mean[EigenvectorCentrality@WeightedAdjacencyGraph@r];*)
  pts = ((BCr - BCm)/BCr)^2 ;
  
  pts *= 1000;
  Return@pts
  ]

pts[adjCitationData, adjPSODynamicsData]
```

I have to calculate the value points for real and modelled network. But when I use the in-built `BetweennessCentrality` of Mathematica, I get all zeros:

```
BetweennessCentrality@WeightedAdjacencyGraph@adjCitationData
{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}
```

I am I using the `BetweennessCentrality` function correctly? Same is the case for closeness and eigenvector centralities.

Comment: The definition you provide is for betweenness, not closeness. The network does not have a closeness centrality, it is the individual vertices that do. Both these measures are already implemented in Mathematica. Can you explain why you want to implement them from scratch?

Comment: To better understand the calculation and later modify as per the need

Comment: What have you tried so far? I assume you found `FindShortestPath`? You can use `FindPath` to find all paths of the same length.

Comment: The title of your post was not consistent with the question asked in the body. I edited it to focus on one specific question. If you have other questions, please ask them in a separate post instead of changing this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasons why centrality functions return all zeros:

- [`WeightedAdjacencyGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedAdjacencyGraph.html) does not work as one would normally expect. This function creates an edge also for matrix entries which are zeros. To indicate the absence of an entry, use `Infinity`. Use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) to change zeros to infinities in your matrix.
- [`BetweennessCentrality`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BetweennessCentrality.html) does not support edge weights. There is no workaround to this using built-in functions.

The simplest way to get around these limitation is to use my package, [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/), which provides a more reasonable [`IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph`](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igweightedadjacencygraph) which treats 0 as a missing edge, and also allows configuring the value that should be interpreted as "unconnected". It also provides [`IGBetweenness`](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#betweenness), which does support weights.